# How do i find value from the collection value of the array by comparing ID in firebase on snapshot in React-native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called doctors. I need to find only that data from collection which has current user inside the allParticipants

ex:

doctors.allParticipants.userID == userID

As you can see in the allParticipants has array of data

is there any way to find this data using where condition or any else please help me to figure out this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array-contains` operator however you need to know the *complete* user object for that as it's an array of object and not strings. For example,

```js
const userObj = {
  channel: "/channels/channelId",
  user: "/users/userId",
  userID: "userId"
}

const colRef = firebase.firestore().collection("channels")
colRef.where("allParticipants", "array-contains", userObj).get().then(snap => {
  console.log(`${snap.size} documents found`)
})
```

If you could store an array of userID (string) only, then the query would be as easy as:

```js
const {uid} = firebase.auth().currentUsers.uid
const query = colRef.where("participantUIDs", "array-contains", uid)
```

But if you need to keep that array of objects, then you'll first need to fetch that user's channel ID and follow method 1.

Comment: @ Dharmaraj i have only userid then how we can find ?

Comment: @SarthakDhami then you can use 2nd method but you'll have to store a separate array of strings i.e. of user IDs only... `["uid1", "uid2"]` you can add a separate field for this as in my answer - "participantUIDs"

Comment: @ Dharmaraj Thanks that array contains thing i know but i want to do find in object of array so please if you have any idea of that let me know.

Comment: @SarthakDhami you'll have to fetch user's channel ID first and then form that userObj as in the answer. There is no other way.

Comment: @ Dharmaraj  if we use array contains method for snapshot then how we use this ?

Comment: I've written the complete query in my answer @SarthakDhami Just copy it and try it out

Comment: if you think my question is good please upvote my question